# MySQL Joining Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to join tables based on conditions

table : main

- condition_field
- unique_id
- username

table : a

- unique_id
- companyname

table : b

- username
- companyname

  **If main.condition_field = "X"**
  I need to Left Join table a on main.unique_id = a.unique_id

  **Else if main.condition_field = "Y"**
  I need to Left Join table b on main.username = b.username

So far I only have this query joining 2 table main and table a

```
SELECT main.*, a.* FROM main LEFT JOIN a ON main.unique_id = a.unique_id where main.unique_id='X'
```

Please Help

---

@Lukas

Thank you very much for that but what is  I have another field [status] in main table and want to add a condition to the query

```
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
```

where can I place the condition clause.

Comment: I love the `SELECT *` pattern!

Answer (score 0):

You can have muliple conditions in the join's `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    main.*,
    CASE main_condition
    WHEN 'X' THEN a.companyname
    WHEN 'Y' THEN b.companyname
    ELSE NULL
    END AS companyname
FROM main
LEFT JOIN a ON main.condition_field = 'X' AND main.unique_id = a.unique_id
LEFT JOIN b ON main.condition_field = 'Y' AND main.username = b.username
WHERE main.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is what you might need to do:

```
SELECT main.*, a.* 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN a ON main.unique_id = a.unique_id 
where main.condition_field='X'

UNION 

SELECT main.*, b.* 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN b ON main.username = b.username 
where main.condition_field='Y'
```